# Which operators be used to access the fields in the object by Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Which of the following Operators can be used to access the fields in the object by Django ORM?

1. (.) Operator
2. (') Operator
3. (,) Operator
4. Both (.) and (') Operator

Answer (score 1):

You use a period (.) to access the fields in the Django ORM object.

This example is from the Django documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/

If a model named Entry is defined as below,

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    mod_date = models.DateField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    number_of_comments = models.IntegerField()
    number_of_pingbacks = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

... then the model can be queried and the fields can be accessed using the dot notation.

```
entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)
print(entry.blog)
print(entry.headline)
```